# Why is there a Segmentation Core dumped? I have made linked lists many times but cannot understand why is there a dump in this code

Tags: c, list

I cannot understand why is there a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"...It happens just when i call the push function inside the push function.

```
node* push(node* head, node*cur, int n)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        ins(n, head);
        head->next=NULL;        
    }
    else
    {
        cur->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));      //because initially head and cur are same!      
        cur=cur->next;
        ins(n, cur);
        cur->next=NULL; 
    }
    printf("\nPress 1 to continue insertion: ");
    int ch; 
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if(ch==1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Digit to push: ");
        int dig;
        scanf("%d", &dig);
        push(head, cur, dig);
    }
    return head;
}


void disp(node* head)
{
    node* cur=head;

    printf("printing::: %d and %d and %p and %p\n", head->dat, cur->next->dat, head, cur);

    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        printf("=>");
        cur=cur->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did....thats how i found out that it happens just before the recursive call

Comment: Show me how you are calling this function.

Comment: What is 'cur' the *first* time you call push()? "//because initially head and cur are same! " - yes, but they're both NULL the first time

Comment: the first time it is same as head

Comment: This does not feel right.

Comment: a few thoughts: 1) always check the returned value from malloc before using it, to assure the operation was successful  2) change the format string on the scanf calls to always have a leading space ' ' so left over white space (like a newline) are consumed/discarded  3) for several reasons, do not cast the returned value from malloc 4) this line: 'if(head==NULL)' is asking of the passed pointer is NULL, I think you want to check if the contents of 'head' is null, suggest: 'if(*head==NULL)'

Comment: @user3629249...i'l definitely incorporate these tips!

Comment: @user3629249...if(*head==NULL) gives an error: invalid operands to binary operator==... head is of type node and NULL is type void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in line

`cur->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` 
because as you said cur is same as head so cur is NULL and accessing next is NULL is invalid.

To cure this do

```
if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        ins(n, head);
        head->next=NULL;  
        cur=head;   // <--change here
    }
```

so that next time cur will point to head and you can access next of cur.

Comment: yes! Perfect....Head was null initially and cur did not get changed when head was allocated memory! Thankyou so much

Comment: .I have edited my code and added a small display function....it is displaying the address and contents of the "head" perfectly...but the moment the while loop starts it goes into a segmentation fault! –

Answer (score 1):

**[Short answer]**
You are trying to do `next` operation over a null pointer

**[Long answer]**
Culprit seems to be `cur` pointer. `Access violation exception` or `Segmentation fault` is flashed when invalid memory is accessed. Here, It seems like cur pointer is null and `->next` operation is being used over null pointer.

**[Solution]**

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ins(n, head);
    head->next=NULL;  
    cur=head;   <---------- Add this
}
```

Comment: That's not really an answer. Needs more explanation about why

Comment: yes culprit is cur here. Aashish please explain more

Comment: @Aashish....I would have loved to upvote your answer but I needed to have 15 reputation score for that.

Comment: @Aashish  ..I have edited my code and added a small display function....it is displaying the address and contents of the "head" perfectly...but the moment the while loop starts it goes into a segmentation fault!

Comment: @Aditya: The problem seems to be with head pointer. You are passing it with `pass by value` in `push` function. Replace it with `pass by address`. It should work fine.

Comment: @Aashish...I am returning the updated address of head back in main()...and passing that updated head to disp()....disp is showing the value stored in head correctly but dumping just when the loop inside disp() starts

Comment: @Aditya: Problem lies here: cur->next->dat. Check if cur->next is null before dereferencing it to get `dat`